# Writing in .txt without erasing the previous

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have notice in my code that, whenever I enter a new input, the previous text I entered is gone and completely being replace by the new one. 
How do I create a new one without removing the previous text?

Here's is my code:

```
String pangalan = nameField.getText().trim();
String edad = age.getText().trim();
if(pangalan.length()!=0&&edad.length()!=0){ 
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Submit Success!");
    mainPanel.add(l1);
    l1.setBounds(70,115,100,100);   
    try{
        input = new Formatter(new File("jj.txt"));              
    }//try
    catch(Exception i){
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }//catch
    input.format("%s %s",pangalan,edad);
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: See [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) and don't use `null` layouts, they will haunt you

Comment: @MadProgrammer Work easily! Thank you master xD

Comment: You can now mark your answer as the answer to this post so others with the same problem can easily see the solution.

Comment: @MatthewC I'll get back in this post in two days :)
`You can accept your own post in 2 days` pops up whenever I click the check button :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the constructors on the java `FileWriter` 1.7
Constructor and Description

```
FileWriter(File file) // Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object.
FileWriter(File file, boolean append) // Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object.
FileWriter(FileDescriptor fd) //Constructs a FileWriter object associated with a file descriptor.
FileWriter(String fileName) // Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name.
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) // Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.
```

Refer to the API for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `FileWriter(File,boolean)` as said by MadProgrammer :) And it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to open the file in append mode, which can be achieved by using the FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) constructor.

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name, true));
```

example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer output;
        try {

            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(("E:\\test.txt"), true));
            output.write("current line");
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output will be ::
[image]

Hope it may help you.